# How to send url params from react to express api call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

So i'm making a fetch request from react to express and the api url requires params but I want the last bit of the url to be dynamic. How would I send a param from react to the api url in express? Heres the code

**react**

```
const [dynamic, setDynamic] = useState("somevalue")

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() { 
        const response = await fetch("/web")
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [dynamic])
```

**express.js**

```
app.get("/web", async (req, res) => {
    const response = await fetch("https://alexa.com/api?Action=urlInfo&Url=")
      const data = await response.json()
      res.json(data)
})
```

Basically, I would like the **dynamic** state value to be injected into the end of the URL in express.

Something like

**react**

```
const [dynamic, setDynamic] = useState("somevalue")

    async function fetchData() { 
        const response = await fetch("/web" + dynamic)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
      }
```

Then in **express** when the API is called the URL changes to

```
const response = await fetch("https://alexa.com/api?Action=urlInfo&Url=somevalue")
```

How can I go about achieving this?

Comment: You can either use query parameters (like `'/web/foo?key1=value1&key2=value2'`) or you can use url parameters (like `'/web/foo/:param1/:param2'`. In the case of url parameters, express does the work for you of matching your request urls to the appropriate handlers and extracting the url parameters as variables in the `request.params` object. In the case of query parameters, those end up in the url no matter what handler is matched and they end up in the `request.query` object. You can use that as a starting point to look further and see which of those methods makes sense for your use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define the parameter on the route handler side, setting up a route that matches the desired pattern.  For example:

```
app.get("/foo/bar/:myparam", async (req, res) => {
    //... here's your handler code
})
```

Will match `/foo/bar/baz`, and `req.params.myparam === "baz"` inside the handler.

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters

Using query params is similar, but you want to check the values of the `req.query` object [instead](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query), like:

```
// client side (React code)
await fetch("/foo/bar?myparam=baz")
...
// In your express handler:
req.query.myparam === "baz"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Dynamic value in params of api call.

React code would look like this:

```
const [dynamic, setDynamic] = useState("somevalue")

useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() { 
    const response = await fetch(`/web/${dynamic}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)
}
fetchData()
}, [dynamic])
```

In Express.Js code
define the parameter on the route handler side, and use that in fetch api call

```
app.get("/web/:value", async (req, res) => {
    const {value} = req.params;  
    const response = await fetch(`https://alexa.com/api?Action=urlInfo&Url=${value}`)
      const data = response.json()
      res.json(data)
})
```